# Cross Slide plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the Ken Burns effect by the code seen on the [click to go to site](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/)
It is working now. But it is not much quality as you can see on this website too. 
It is not smooth and looks bit vibrating.

Can anyone tell me a way to smooth this animation like we can see on Visual Slideshow software??

Thanks!!

Comment: try [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) or [Nivoslider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

Comment: Your plugin hasn't been updated in two years.  Try a newer plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that details rolling your own: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/

It also includes a link to [download the plug-in](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/downloads/jquery.crossfade.js) that they detail.